# Draw connections/paths between elements in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-phone

I am currently developing an app where you can move different elements (boxes) and I need to display several arrows between them to show off connections and data flows. I don't want to use simple lines because this looks crappy. I recently used this great JavaScript library which does the thing I need for HTML: http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html

Is there something similar for XAML out there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use bezie curves. From MSDN

> To create a quadratic Bezier curve, use the PathGeometry, PathFigure, and QuadraticBezierSegment classes.

Simple example for creating [bezie curves](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752367.aspx)